# How to search for a particular word in whole document in firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make an android app for college. I have a collection named users. All the students who create accounts are stored in this collection within a document named same as their particular UID. I have a field inside every document named admission_id which contains a unique id. Whenever a student creates an account, he/she needs to enter a unique admission_id. I need to check whether the entered admission id is unique or not.

```
collectionReference = (CollectionReference) fStore.collection("Users");
Query query = collectionReference
        .whereEqualTo("Admission", "1234");
query.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
        Toast.makeText(CreateStudent.this, "Admission ID already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

I tried the above code but it always returns true.
I want to check 1234 in all the collections "Admission" field and display toast if it exist.

Comment: So you want to check if a particular id already exists, right?

Comment: yes
I want to alert the user if the id "1234" already exists in the Admission field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onSuccess` will always be called, even when there are no results.

To check whether there are any results for the query, check `queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()`.

```
query.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
        if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(CreateStudent.this, "Admission ID already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not working for me.
It always displays the same toast even if it doesn't exist

Comment: That seems odd. If you set a breakpoint on `if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) ` and run in a debugger, does it indeed show that `isEmpty()` returns false? If so, can you edit your question to include a screenshot of the document you expect the query to match?

Comment: Hey @JerinReji Did you get anywhere with this? If it's not sorted yet, can you check my comment above and provide more information on what happens in the debugger?

Comment: Thankyou for your response. It's working fine now. Actually it was my mistake, I was using query instead of task.

Comment: I am trying to get the values from that current document in which  the admission ID exists. I tried it with documentSnapshot.getString("field") inside the query, but it's not working. Can you please suggest any way to do so.